# Value of x when equation reaches maximum?

Tags: calculus, optimization

How can I find the value of $x$ when $y$ reaches its maximum value or goes to infinity?

$$y=\frac12A(1+\cosh{(x\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}})})$$

$A,B$ are constant, and $x$ ranges from $0$ to $0.001$.

Comment: When $y \to \infty$ you must have $x \to \infty$, you can't limit it to $0.001$  For large values of the argument, $\cosh z \approx \frac 12 \exp z$

Comment: no if you plot $cosh$ you see that a value of $x$ when $y$ go to $infinity$

Comment: $\cosh z = \frac 12(\exp (z) + \exp(-z))$  It has no poles.  You are getting fooled by the fast rise of the exponential

Comment: I don't care about $-z$

Comment: $\cosh z$ is symmetric in $z$.  It goes to infinity like $\frac 12\exp z$, but doesn't blow up for any finite $z$.  What value of $z$ do you think takes $\cosh z$ to $\infty?$

Answer (score 0):

For the question you asked, since $\cosh$ is monotonically increasing for the argument greater than $0$, the maximum comes at the highest argument.  Since $x$ is restricted to $0.001$ maximum, that is where your maximum $y$ occurs.

Comment: actually it should be go to infinity , i need to find x before it go to infinity ? how do that  ?

Comment: I don't understand this comment at all.  You seem to think $\cosh z$ goes to $\infty$ for finite $z$.  This is wrong.  It rises rapidly, but is finite for all finite $z$, unlike (for example) $\frac 1{z-10}$, which goes to $\infty$ at $z=10$

Comment: so how can find x before cosh x go to infinity ? that what i need ?

Comment: You want the highest $x$ that is permitted.  It seems that is $0.001$, so that is what you need.

Comment: you don't understand me :(

Comment: That seems to be true.  I am trying to help, but your previous two comments left me guessing.  In your original question, when you said $x$ range from $0$ to $0.001$ I thought that $x$ was not allowed to go outside that.  Unless you have a maximum allowed $x\ $, $y$ will increase as $x$ increases.  There will be no maximum.  It is just like $y=\exp(ax)$ Maybe you are confusing rising very rapidly (which exp does) with rising to infinity at a finite value (which $\frac 1{x-10}$ does)  Those are very different behaviors.